# Reading geometries storaged as a CSV file created in R

Tags: r, geometry

I received a CSV file created in R with some information of tracts in the District of Columbia and their geometries. However, the format is strange to me, and I cannot convert it into a shapefile.

The geometries are presented as follows:

```
list(c(-77.002011, -76.999051, -76.995986, -76.994548, -76.989257, -76.989521, -76.98902, -76.988895, -76.99705, -77.000043, -77.000329, -77.002011, 38.951051, 38.951842, 38.951996, 38.952295, 38.952409, 38.948629, 38.946757, 38.946269, 38.94627, 38.94627, 38.946972, 38.951051))
```

How can I use it as a polygon and then convert it into a shape file?

Comment: Is this the actual file content? If yes, it's a `dput()` output that you can read  with `dget()` , i.e. something like `inlst <- dget("mysteriousfile"); matrix(inlst[[1]], ncol = 2)` would provide you coordinate pairs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the list contains a numeric vector which, when converted into a two-column matrix, will provide longitude / latitude columns describing the vertices of a polygon. You could therefore do:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

df <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(lapply(data, matrix, ncol = 2)), crs = "WGS84"))
st_geometry(df) <- "geometry"
```

Result:

```r
df
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -77.00201 ymin: 38.94627 xmax: -76.9889 ymax: 38.95241
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((-77.00201 38.9510...
```

We can confirm this is correct by plotting the polygon in red over a black-and-white map of the DC area, where we see this polygon coincides nicely with a boundary created by existing roads:

```r
library(ggmap)

m <- get_stamenmap(c(bottom = 38.94, top = 38.96, 
                     left = -77.01, right = -76.98), 
                   zoom = 15, maptype = "toner-lite")

ggmap(m) + geom_sf(data = df, inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = "red", alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used**

```r
data <- list(c(-77.002011, -76.999051, -76.995986, -76.994548, -76.989257,
               -76.989521, -76.98902, -76.988895, -76.99705, -77.000043,
               -77.000329, -77.002011, 38.951051, 38.951842, 38.951996, 38.952295,
               38.952409, 38.948629, 38.946757, 38.946269, 38.94627, 38.94627,
               38.946972, 38.951051))
```